# PowerBI running total on large data

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
    column = 

var date = table[date] 

var id = table[part id] 

var filtered_table = filter(table,table[date]<date && table[part id] = id) 

return calculate(sum(table[qty]),filtered_table )
```

I am trying to run this running total on 3.4million records to calc the total quantity used of a part before the date of the current record. This keeps running out of memory how can I streamline this query to get it to work